# get Unread message's number from different chat room in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have three collections, `User`, `Room`, `RoomMessage`.
`User` collection stores the user information, it has a field named 'rooms' which is an array storing all the rooms that this user belong. And for each room it has a `timestamp` field, so we can decide the unread messages from this room.

```
rooms: [{
    room: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Room'
    },
    timestamp: {
       type: Date,
       default: Date.now()
    }
}]
```

And the following this `RoomMessage` Collections which stores all the message

```
var RoomMessageSchema = new Schema({
    sender: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    room: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Room'
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    type: String,
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

Now let say `user1` belongs to 10 rooms and there is a room-list in his page displaying all the rooms that is belong, and it can shows all the unread messages number for each room.
How should I do it? Can I make this query faster?

Comment: How do you determine if a message is unread?